# Is it normal to wait for some time between operations under the VISA protocol?

Tags: python, visa

I am using [pyvisa](https://github.com/hgrecco/pyvisa) to program a power supply which conforms to the SCPI protocol, like this:

```
power = get_power()
power.write('VOLTage 24.000')
time.sleep(1)       # **Must delay**
power.query(u'VOLTage?')
disconnect_power(power)
```

Everything was OK, but if I didn't wait between 'write' and 'query', then there was a timeout error, just like this:

> raise errors.VisaIOError(ret_value)
>   pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.

Is it normal to delay between operations when programming such instrument under VISA protocol? If not, what is the usual way? Or is there any mechanism like Event? If yes, how do I decide the latency time?

Comment: Looks like a SCPI instrument. Timeouts are common when the data sent is not understood. Try querying the error queue after the timeout. Also watch for messages displayed on the front panel if the instrument has one.

Comment: As I understood, there should be an interval between operations for the instrument to response, the interval time depends on baud rate.

Comment: The session timeout setting should be more than long enough for the instrument to read the input, perform a few commands and respond to a query. Timeout should only occur due to severe communications issues, say 10 or 20 seconds. The stimulus-response design of SCPI doesn't allow the instrument to respond when it doesn't understand what it receives. That's why you might get a timeout from a query where there is really not a bus-level communications problem.

Comment: I think section 'Command Delays' in this article [link](http://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=MY&lc=eng&ckey=558637&nid=-536900124.0&id=558637#Command Delays) explains my confusion.

Comment: So you are using RS-232? You should look up the handshaking options supported by the instrument, pick one and configure the VISA session appropriately. If the instrument supports any handshaking methods, then VISA will handle it and the concern mentioned in the article won't apply. So, no, it is not normal to program waits in client code when using the VISA protocol.

Comment: @ Tom Blodget Following your opinion, and after reading protocols such as scpi-99, IEEE-488.2, IEEE-488.1 carefully, I have found a satisfied method for synchronization, like this:`power = get_power()
power.write('VOLTage 24.000;*OPC?')
power.read()
power.query(u'VOLTage?')
disconnect_power(power)` So that's it. *OPC? is the stand synchronization command. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, this is a common problem when programming an [SCPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Commands_for_Programmable_Instruments) instrument.  Actually, SCPI provides many methods for synchronization, see IEEE-488.2.87 section 12: Device/Controller Synchronization Techniques. And [here](https://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/application_notes/1gp79/1GP79_1E_SCPI_Programming_Guide_SigGens.pdf) is a summary for good SCPI programming practices, although it's for a proprietary instrument, some tips apply to all SCPI devices.

So the key issue is: The power supply can not process the next 'Program Message' (refer to IEEE-488.2.87 for details) before the previous ('VOLTage 24.000') is completed. If you force to do it without a proper delay, the processing will be interrupted.

SCPI provides a synchronization command, "*OPC?" to wait for all commands before it to complete. When every command completes, it will put a 1 in output buffer. So we can just append '*OPC?' to the previous Program Message and then just wait for completion by read, after that we query, like this:

```
power = get_power()
power.write('VOLTage 24.000;*OPC?')
power.read()
power.query(u'VOLTage?')
disconnect_power(power)
```

So that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The *WAI command can be used in place of the *OPC? query.

```
power = get_power()

voltage_read = power.query('VOLTage 24.000;*WAI;u'VOLTage?')

disconnect_power(power)
```

The *WAI instructs the instrument to wait for the completion for setting  the voltage, before reading back the query.